# Can't understand how vertical alignment to a base line should be computed using stb_truetype library for SDF fonts?

Tags: c++, graphics, fonts, text-rendering

So, the question looks simple, but I still can't understand how properly compute a vertical alignment of glyphs when we use SDF generated bitmaps using **stb_truetype** library.

In nutshell I have own texture packer system that generates a texture atlas with all needed SDF represented glyphs. Also there is a data type that contains the following parameters per code point including width, height, xoff and yoff, which I get from **stbtt_GetCodepointSDF** function.

I've checked up a few listings including this [one](https://github.com/nothings/stb/blob/master/tests/sdf/sdf_test.c), but it didn't help me. So what's the right formula?